# How to prepare the Stern-Gerlach experiment for a particular state?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, hilbert-space

If we want to form a diagram or calculate the angles at which the magnets need to be positioned in the Stern-Gerlach setup, how do we proceed? For example, if I want to prepare the following state,

$$|\psi\rangle= |{\uparrow_z} \rangle+2|{\downarrow_z} \rangle$$

how do I calculate the angles? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I understand that you speak of a fermion beam.
Then take in consideration that a state $|\psi(\theta)\rangle$ of polarization $\theta$ i.e. at an angle $\theta$ with respect to the $z$ axis, can be expressed as

$$|\psi(\theta)\rangle = \cos \left(\frac {\theta}{2} \right)|\uparrow\rangle + \sin \left(\frac {\theta}{2} \right)|\downarrow\rangle$$

So the state you seek makes with the axis $z$ an angle defined by

$$cos(\theta) = \cos^2 \left(\frac {\theta}{2}\right) - \sin^2 \left(\frac {\theta}{2} \right) = \left(\frac {1}{\sqrt {5}} \right)^2 - \left(\frac {2}{\sqrt {5}} \right)^2 = \frac {4}{5}.$$

Two options now:

**A)** First of all decide which axis in the space is $z$, orient the magnetic field in your SG apparatus in the direction $-z$ (because spin $z$ fermions will go in the direction $-z$ of the field), and then rotate the apparatus by $\theta$.

**B)** A more difficult option is that after orientating the magnetic field along $-z$, to select from the $|\uparrow\rangle$ beam, with a beam-splitter, a thinner beam with 1/4 intensity. Nex, by means of an opposite SG apparatus, to merge this beam with the one with $|\downarrow\rangle$. This option is rather theoretical because one should be very careful to have the beams coming to the 2nd SG ***in phase***, which is not simple, and even so, the precision of the merging is very poor.